# a pointer points to an object in vector after sorting(C++)

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers

There are structs like these

```cpp
class Component {
    string name;
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct Relation_h { // also for Relation_v (h for horizontal, v for vertical)
    Component *;
    //some data in here;
};
```

I have a initial vector `vector<Component> data` and `vector<list<Relation>> relation_h and relation_v`

I want to `sort the vector data` corresponding to its x and y respectively then construct the relations
and the `Component* actually points to the data[i] for i in range(0, data.size())`

But the problem is that `the pointer points to is not the original object which I want to access after sorting with x and y`

Is there way to deal with this situation?

Comment: Probably the trick is not to try and sort the data itself.  [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46382252/sort-array-by-first-item-in-subarray-c/46382976#46382976).  In short, have an index array and sort that instead, based on the original sort criteria.  Then use the index array to access the elements in a sorted manner.  And also, please post a [mcve] -- we have no idea what you're doing when you say you're sorting the data.

Comment: Also, there is no need for pointers here.  You have a vector of objects -- where would anything to do with pointers be relevant?  Maybe it's because you didn't think of doing things in the way I suggested in the first comment?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for answer, the reason I want to sort the data is that when I construct the relation_h or relation_v just for convinient of push_back directly

Comment: Well, I can't easily post an answer to code that isn't shown.  However from your description, using an index array and sorting that would seem to accomplish your goal easily.

Comment: the vector data is the name of vector, sorry for that

Comment: Please don't edit answers into the question, if you've solved your problem you can post an answer to your own question

Comment: An array with pointers to the elements of the `data` vector is in most cases easier to use than an index array. Btw: technically it's not the adresses of objects that change, but the data in the existing objects is swapped...

Comment: @fabian I understand that technically , thanks for remind that, I will revise the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One such solution (but of course, not the only one) as mentioned in the comments is to use an auxiliary index array as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46382252/sort-array-by-first-item-in-subarray-c/46382976#46382976)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>

//...
struct Component {
    std::string name;
    int x;
    int y;
    Component(int val1, int val2) : x(val1), y(val2) {}
};
//...
int main()
{
    std::vector<Component> vComponents = { {2,3},{1,2},{0,2},{12,-2},{3,4},{-6,1} };

    // Create the index array (0,1,2,3,4,...)
    std::vector<int> index(vComponents.size());
    std::iota(index.begin(), index.end(), 0);

    //Print original
    std::cout << "Original order:\n";
    for (auto i : index)
        std::cout << vComponents[i].x << " " << vComponents[i].y << "\n";

    // Sort the index array, based on the x, y criteria
    std::sort(index.begin(), index.end(), [&](int n1, int n2)
        { return std::tie(vComponents[n1].x, vComponents[n1].y) <
                 std::tie(vComponents[n2].x, vComponents[n2].y); });
    //...
    // Print sorted
    std::cout << "\nSorted order:\n";
    for (auto i : index)
        std::cout << vComponents[i].x << " " << vComponents[i].y << ":    Location is at " << i << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Original order:
2 3
1 2
0 2
12 -2
3 4
-6 1

Sorted order:
-6 1:    Location is at 5
0 2:    Location is at 2
1 2:    Location is at 1
2 3:    Location is at 0
3 4:    Location is at 4
12 -2:    Location is at 3
```

There are a few things to note:

1. The index array is the array that's sorted.  The indices given to the `std::sort` predicate are used for the comparison within the `vComponents` vector.
2. The usage of `std::tie` makes it trivial to compare "cascading" members, such as `x` and then `y`.

You then use the `index` array to access the elements.  You keep the order of the elements intact, but have the index array that indicates where the "sorted" item is located.