# How to sort an vector based on any column value by passing the column index as input?

Tags: c++, vector, 2d-vector

I have already tried the below code but i want to use this same function for sorting based on different columns.

This given code is sorting based on first column only.

```
bool sortcol( const vector <int> v1, const vector <int> v2)
{
return v1[0]<v2[0];
}

sort(ArrOfTimings.begin(), ArrOfTimings.end(), sortcol);
```

Is there any way possible to not make multiple functions but making it all work with one only.

Something like this

```
bool sortcol(int ind, const vector <int> v1, const vector <int> v2)
{
return v1[ind]<v2[ind];
}

sort(ArrOfTimings.begin(), ArrOfTimings.end(), sortcol(0));
```

Comment: What if those vectors contain thousands of elements?  A better approach would be to sort an index array instead of swapping out entire vectors on each out-of-order item.

Comment: that way i might lose data. The data in each vector is related.

Comment: You are not losing any data.  The index tells you where the sorted items are.  See my answer below.

Comment: Also [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46382252/sort-array-by-first-item-in-subarray-c/46382976#46382976).  I will probably remove my answer, and have you take a look at this answer, as it explains everything to you.  In that example, the sorting is done on column 0, but all you have to do is replace the `0` with `column`.  Everything else basically stays the same.  If you want an example: [see this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48ab6e65d451ccef).

Comment: okay now I get it. Its good when vector contains large number of items. I used this method too but it takes extra space thats why swapping vectors themselves. My vectors have only three elements anyways, so

Comment: I provided the comments to the alternate solution in case others are doing a search for the same thing you are doing, but want to use an index array (or are not aware of it, and then see that it is a better solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass additional info to a free function used for comparison for `std::sort` by means other than global data.

You can create a struct with a member variable storing the column to compare in addition to providing a call operator for comparing the values though.

I'd prefer a lambda, since it results in shorter code though: Simply capture the index.

Note: It's also beneficial to avoid copying the vector by using references as parameters.

```
void SortByColumn(std::vector<std::vector<int>> & data, size_t column)
{
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(),
              [column](std::vector<int> const& v1, std::vector<int> const& v2)
              {
                  return v1[column] < v2[column];
              });
}
```

Comment: Can the lambda take an additional argument to use in the comparison? for instance, a string ("ASC" or "DSC") that will determine if the sorting is ascending or descending

Comment: @Barbarossa You cannot add a function parameter, since `std::sort` passes 2 parameters to the functor. You can add more stuff to the capture though, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture. Personally I'd prefer doing the case distinction outside of the lambda though and using 2 separate calls to `std::sort` with 2 different lambdas based on the string...

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the lambda function.  The link is perfect, thanks!  I wasn't sure if it would go inside the captures, or the params.