# Sorting vectors of vectors in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, stdvector

Can we sort vectors of vectors like:

```cpp
{[7, 2], [1, 8], [3, 4]}
```

using `std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end())`, according to first element in each vector in ascending order, or do we need to pass custom comparator function to `std::sort`?

Comment: If you have `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, you can use `std::sort`, but you will need a custom comparator.  The `vec.begin()` and `vec.end()`, are for **one** vector, not nested vectors.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, it should work out of the box. `std::vector` does provide a comparison operator that would sort in lexicographical order, which in turn implies being sorted by the first element. In your example, the result would be `[ [1, 8], [3, 4], [7, 2] ]` - is this what you expect?

Comment: Please clarify how you want your matrix sorted.

Comment: What have you tried? What version of C++ standard can you use? (this will impact how much boiler plate code is needed).

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46382252/sort-array-by-first-item-in-subarray-c)

Comment: if the elements are always 2 items like that then using a vector of vector is a very bad idea. Use `std::vector<std::pair>` instead, or create a vector of struct like `struct coord { int x; int y }; std::vector<coord>`. Using `std::pair` has the advantage that the `operator<` is available and you can sort the vector directly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort vectors of vectors without any custom comparators.
If you don't provide one, then [`std::vector::operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) will be used.
This operator performs a lexicographical comparison of the elements inside.

For example:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vecs{{7, 2}, {1, 8, 5}, {3}};
    
    // until C++20
    std::sort(vecs.begin(), vecs.end());

    // since C++20
    std::ranges::sort(vecs);

    for (const auto &v : vecs) {
        for (int x : v) {
            std::cout << x << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
1 8 5 
3 
7 2
```

Note: the `operator<` will first compare the first element, and if it's the same in both vectors, it will compare the remaining elements.
If you *only* want to compare the first element to save performance, you still need a custom comparator, which you could do as follows:

```cpp
// since C++11, could also be written as a lambda expression
struct first_element_compare {
    
    /* static since C++23*/
    constexpr bool operator()(const std::vector<int>& a,
                              const std::vector<int>& b) const
    {
        // FIXME: this code crashes when a or b is empty
        //        we must decide how these vectors compare to each other
        return a.front() < b.front();
    }
};

// ...

// until C++20
std::sort(vecs.begin(), vecs.end(), first_element_compare{});

// since C++20
std::ranges::sort(vecs, first_element_compare{});
```

Comment: The OP wants to: *sort accordingto first value of vector in increasing orde*

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike yes. This code sorts according to the first value (`1`, `3`, `7`) of each vector in ascending order.

Comment: It does more than that, but I guess it has to otherwise just using the fiorst element wouldn't maintain a strict weak ordering.

Comment: A strict weak ordering can have elements that compare equal even though they are not the same, and it can also have incomparable elements as long as incomparability is transitive.

Comment: Projection is nice feature to use here: https://godbolt.org/z/KKdax1v53 Sadly you can't use `&std::vector<int>::front` since it returns reference and as result deduction fails.