# How to use std::sort to loop through one variable within a struct and rearrange another?

Tags: c++, sorting, optimization, particles, particle-system

I'm honestly at a loss as to why my question is being called a duplicate as all the other examples show how to sort a variable within a struct. I am trying to sort a variable within a struct based on another, and this I cannot find examples of. Below is my question in the hopes someone can help:

I have a rudimentary particle system I've developed for learning.

My main particle is contained in a struct which looks like this:

```
struct Particle {
float px;  // x-position
float py;  // y-position
float pz;  // z-position
float scale;
float rotation;
float red;
float green;
float blue;
float alpha;
int index; };
```

Index is the particle ID. As I create each new particle, it gets saved into the Particle vector array called `std::vector<Particle> particles;` which I increment by one. Finally, I draw them after that.

I now want to introduce a pass for depth sorting, so that I can draw the particles from furthest to closest.

I understand that std::sort will work. My understanding is that I need to loop through the particles.pz (z position) but apply that sorting result to particles.index. So the index will ultimately be rearranged and hold the correct drawing order. I have this working already but not using std::sort and it is painfully slow. Thus, I'm hoping std::sort will provide a boost in performance.

I see that to do that, you can sort through the struct like this:

```
    std::sort(particles.begin(), particles.end(), [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs)
        {
            return lhs.pz1 > rhs.pz1;
        });
```

But this will rearrange the z positions whereas I want to rearrange the particle index BASED on the z position sort. I've looked at many other examples but none seem to address this.

I am not so experienced with structs, let alone sorting, so obviously I am doing something wrong.

How can I modify this code so that it sorts through the particle z positions from furthest to closest, and applies that sorting to the particle index?

ADDENDUM:

Perhaps this will help. This code shows my current sorting algorithm and how it works. I am trying to optimize this and see if std::sort can perform better. This is before I was using my struct so the variables are named differently and I hope I copied it correctly but it is mainly for illustrative purposes. (Counter is total particles).

```
            for (int i = 0; i < counter - 1; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < counter - 1; ++j) {
                int p = particles[j].index;
                int q = particles[j + 1].index;

                if ( particles[p].pz > particles[q].pz) {
                    unsigned int tmp = particles[j].index;
                    particles[j].index = particles[j + 1].index;
                    particles[j + 1].index = tmp;

                }
            }
        }
```

CONCLUSION:

@PaulMcKenzie was able to help me understand and solve this. He went the extra mile to write out example code which I will post below as my accepted answer. After having to do some minor adjustments, I can confirm his solution works and it is much faster. Whereas my tests came in at 16 seconds of computation his solution using std::sort brought it down to 3.8 seconds. Thanks again!

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

struct Particle {
float px;  // x-position
float py;  // y-position
float pz;  // z-position
float scale;
float rotation;
float red;
float green;
float blue;
float alpha;
};

int main()
{
    // random number generator
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> zValues(1.0f, 1000.0f);
   
    // Fill vector with random z values
    std::vector<Particle> vParticles(10);
    for (auto& v : vParticles )
       v.pz = zValues(gen);

    std::vector<int> index(10);
    std::cout << "Original order by z:\n";
    for (auto& v : vParticles)        
      std::cout << v.pz << "\n";

    // set up index array
    std::iota(index.begin(), index.end(), 0);

    // Sort via the index
    std::sort(index.begin(), index.end(), [&](int n1, int n2) 
        { return vParticles[n1].pz < vParticles[n2].pz;});

    std::cout << "\nSorted order by z:\n";
    for (auto& i : index)        
      std::cout << vParticles[i].pz << " " << " is at index " << i << "\n";

    std::cout << "\nHere is the final index array:\n";
    for (auto& i : index)        
        std::cout << i << "\n";

    std::cout << "\nProof that vector has not changed:\n";
    for (auto& v : vParticles)        
      std::cout << v.pz << "\n";
}
```

Comment: *I understand that both std::sort and std::qsort will work* -- If you change your `struct` to contain a member that is not trivially-copyable, `qsort` is no longer an option.  You should use `std::sort` and pretend `qsort` does not exist.

Comment: `std::sort(particles.begin(), particles.end(), &particles_sorter)` -- You could have used a lambda and not have to write a separate sort-comparison function.  [See the examples here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: you should prefer `std::sort` with a lambda over `qsort` , because `std::sort` with a lambda will inline the comparison operation, which is much much faster, the only downside is a slightly bloated binary.

Comment: To address my first comment, here is [qsort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort), and read the following statement from that page:  *If the type of the elements of the array is not a PODType (until C++11) TriviallyCopyable type (since C++11), the behavior is undefined.*.  The reason why `qsort` cannot be used for those types is that the implementation assumes the language being used is `C`, not C++.  Thus `qsort` may use `memcpy` or some other `C` function to move items around.  A `memcpy` being done on a non-trivial type is deadly.

Comment: Hi @PaulMcKenzie - they closed my question but I didn't see in any other examples how to use one variable from a struct to sort another. That is what I'm trying to achieve. Loop through the z positions and apply that sorting to the particle index, so that I can draw them in the correct order. Can you help me with that? (And yes, it appears that I should use std::sort.

Comment: @Rich95 — edit your question to more clearly say what your goal is.

Comment: @PeteBecker - I did about 5 minutes ago and nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: the most efficient solution i can think of is to create a vector of `Particle*` to elements of the first vector, sort that, then update the `index` based on its position in that vector of pointers.

Comment: If you use the comparator that you’ve shown your vector will be rearranged so that the particles it holds are sorted with the furthest away first and the nearest last.

Comment: @PeteBecker - But that's not working for me. What I need to do is rearrange the order of particles.index based on the sorting of z position of the particles. Then I can draw them correctly. At least that is what I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: @Rich95 *I want to rearrange the particle index BASED on the z position sort* -- Then this really is not a `std::sort` issue.  The issue is coming up with a function that when given two `Particle` objects, which object should be placed before the other when sorted.    That is basically all `std::sort` is doing -- giving you two objects, and you writing a function to tell `std::sort` which item comes before the other.  That function can be simple, complex, or something in-between -- `std::sort` doesn't care, as long as it follows a strict-weak-ordering.

Comment: @Rich95 i am wondering why are you using the `.index` member to arrange the drawing instead of using its position in the vector ? using the position in the vector should be faster, you don't seem to even need this `.index` member.

Comment: I have edited the message and posted my current sorting example to help clarify what I am trying to achieve. Perhaps I have confused myself and not asked the question correctly, or misunderstood how std::sort works.

Comment: @Rich95 From your last edit, it seems what you are actually doing is essentially sorting an array of indices based on the `z` value.  If that is correct, then [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46382252/sort-array-by-first-item-in-subarray-c/46382976#46382976).

Comment: @Rich95 -- Are you looking for something [like this?](https://godbolt.org/z/znj8fxffK).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hi Paul - in my case, the index (which is the particle ID) is also a member of the particle struct.

Comment: @Rich95 Look at the output that shows the indices where you see `Here is the final index array:`.   Given the test data, are those the index numbers you expected to see for each particle *after* you had done your theoretical sorting?  If so, just go through the particles and assign those index numbers to them when the sorting is done.  This is different than what you were doing, where you were assigning an index as soon as you created a particle.   Instead, the indices are "assigned" according to the sort.

Comment: @Rich95 -- [Here is the output showing the number and the index](https://godbolt.org/z/v6xn81nP4).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hi Paul! That does indeed work! I made the index a separate vector outside of the struct like you did. I have to make some other changes to my code to make it work completely but as a rough, preliminary implementation, it does work. Not only that, but the same sort that took 16 seconds with my current implementation took just around 3 seconds with std::sort! So thank you for your help and taking the time to show me how to do it. I will do the full implementation over the weekend and let you know how it went. :)

Comment: Why are you keeping the index inside that `struct`? It is possible to work it out but this design seems to be expensive to maintain. If you provide a sample code for the usage after sort, then better advice can come.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, after some minor adjustments, I was able to fully implement your example code and it worked beautifully. Speed gains were fantastic. I edited my question to include your answer. I don't know how I can mark your comment as the accepted answer so if you know, feel free to share. Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: @Rich95 -- You can post your final solution as an answer so that it can get upvoted.   I didn't want to initially post my code as an answer, since I was not sure if the code I had is what was desired.  Include in your answer any updates my code did not have, as long as what is included can be compiled and run, basically a [mcve] (but in answer form).

Answer (score 1):

@PaulMcKenzie was able to help me understand and solve this. He went the extra mile to write out example code which I will post below as my accepted answer. After having to do some minor adjustments, I can confirm his solution works and it is much faster. Whereas my tests came in at 16 seconds of computation his solution using std::sort brought it down to 3.8 seconds. Thanks again!

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

struct Particle {
float px;  // x-position
float py;  // y-position
float pz;  // z-position
float scale;
float rotation;
float red;
float green;
float blue;
float alpha;
};

int main()
{
    // random number generator
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> zValues(1.0f, 1000.0f);
   
    // Fill vector with random z values
    std::vector<Particle> vParticles(10);
    for (auto& v : vParticles )
       v.pz = zValues(gen);

    std::vector<int> index(10);
    std::cout << "Original order by z:\n";
    for (auto& v : vParticles)        
      std::cout << v.pz << "\n";

    // set up index array
    std::iota(index.begin(), index.end(), 0);

    // Sort via the index
    std::sort(index.begin(), index.end(), [&](int n1, int n2) 
        { return vParticles[n1].pz < vParticles[n2].pz;});

    std::cout << "\nSorted order by z:\n";
    for (auto& i : index)        
      std::cout << vParticles[i].pz << " " << " is at index " << i << "\n";

    std::cout << "\nHere is the final index array:\n";
    for (auto& i : index)        
        std::cout << i << "\n";

    std::cout << "\nProof that vector has not changed:\n";
    for (auto& v : vParticles)        
      std::cout << v.pz << "\n";
}
```